# How get Singular.m package to interact with Singular itself?

Tags: packages

I've installed the package `Singular.m` by Kauers and Levandovskyy from http://www.risc.uni-linz.ac.at/research/combinat/software/Singular/ as well as the Singular CAS itself. How, exactly does one get the package to communicate with the Singular system -- specifically to get results back from Singular to Mathematica?

In a terminal, I just type `singular` and that starts the system. So at the end of the package `.m` file I modified the final line so it now reads `SingularCommand = "singular"`. Now after I load the package and evaluate one of the interface functions, such as one in the `demo.nb` notebook, I get an error: `Singular::error : Unable to read Singular's output.`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I found the same issue and resolved it by changing the name of `SingularCommand` from just `Singular` to it's full path at line 245 of the Singular.m package.  On my Mac, this was `/usr/local/bin/Singular` but your system may be different.

Comment: That did it! Thanks, @Mark McClure